# Symbol PocketBrowser alternative for free

Tags: browser, barcode-scanner

I Need to create web page that can communicate with barcode Scanner on windows mobile

Symbol Pocket Browser is Not free

Is there alternative?

Comment: OK, there is no free browser with EMML (Motorola) support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Pocket browser does is call the motorola Dll from the web page. it is using EMML (Enterprise Mobility Mark-up Language) which basically wraps the Motorola DLLs making their functionality available withing your HTML page. So if you want to create your own PB, find out how to call a local DLL from a local HTML. You can render the page using IE engine.

I'm not aware of any free software similar to this for Windows mobile. Now PB has evolved and it is called RhoElements, which belongs to the RhoMobile suit, also from Motorola.

Answer (score -1):

Symbol Pocket Browser is app compatible with Symbol/Motorola devices.
I thikn they usually  have some sort of keyboard wedge software available for free.
( datawedge ). Should not be problem to use that and handle barcode scanner from html as
keyboard input.

Comment: keyboard wedge is not very suitable for web forms